# How to prevent registration of certain usernames in web2py?

Tags: web2py, user-registration

I've enabled user names in auth by doing:

```
auth.define_tables(username=True)
```

How can I prevent users from registering with names in a blacklist, such as:

```
admin
administrator
moderator
sysadmin
```

and possibly offensive words

**Update**

Here's the username validator that I made:

```
class UsernameValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, error_message='Invalid username'):
        self.error_message = error_message
    def __call__(self, value):
        if self.validate(value):
            return (value, None)
        else:
            return (value, self.error_message)

    def validate(self, value):
        blacklist = ['administrator', 'moderator', 'admin', '<swear word>']
        if any(word in value for word in blacklist):
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I put this in a model file with a filename starting with "0" so it would be loaded before db.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def validate_username(form):
    if form.vars.username in ['admin', 'administrator', 'moderator']:
        form.errors.username = '%s is not a valid username.' % \
                               form.vars.username

auth.settings.register_onvalidation.append(validate_username)
```

You can also create a [custom validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Custom-validators) and do:

```
db.auth_user.username.requires.append(MyCustomValidator())
```